# ArcMap populate field with value from another dataset

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, spatial-join

I have two Polygon datasets, one contains Buildings and the other PostCodes (ZipCodes). I'd like the PostCode field in the Buildings dataset to be populated with the value of the PostCode field from that dataset.  Using ArcMap 10.2.2 is this possible?

Comment: I'm guessing there's a [Join Data](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005s0000002q000000) function in ArcMap which might do what you're looking for (note that both may datasets may require a common attribute to correctly apply each postcode to their relevant building).

Answer (score 3):

Use the tool "Spatial Join" from within the Arc Toolbox, if you are searching for the tool ensure you type out the complete phrase as ArcMap's search facility is not very good at partial matches!

Then select:

"Target Features" = buildings layer.
"Join features "  = postcode layer

All other settings should be ok by default, click go and it will run. (It will transfer all of the fields from the postcode layer to the buildings layer by default, this can be changed using the field map are at the bottom of the screen.)

Comment: There is indeed both a "Spatial Join" tool, and an "Add Join" tool. The add join tool requires a common field and joins the data where the values match, however in this case, the "spatial join" tool uses the spatial location of the features, by default it will match each building to the polygon it is "within".

Comment: Thankyou, that seems to have worked pretty well.  It's a shame I cannot match the two fields together though as I now have two 'PostCode' fields on account of them not being the same field name in each dataset.

Comment: Yes it creates a new field, you can now delete one of them for cleanliness.

You could also do some "Select by Attributes" and "Field Calculator" to update one field into the other. (To update it for example) and then delete the field after required edits are made.

Comment: AS Luke says this is just a basic old fundamental SJ.